# Auto increment issue in SQlite3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I have a table in Sqlite3 :

```
CREATE TABLE `shows` (
    `index` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `show`  TEXT,
    `createddate`   TEXT,
    `Batch` INTEGER
);
```

I'm loading data into the table using code below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([shows,dates, batch]),columns=['show', 'createddate','batch'])

df.to_sql('shows', conn,if_exists='append')
```

The first time I ran it with the table empty it works fine.

But if I run it again I get an error :

```
 UNIQUE constraint failed: shows.index
```

Any ideas how I can get the index to auto-increment for the second load?

Edit : Show, Dates, Batch are just lists of text data.  You'll notice I'm not passing in the index as don't think I need to with AUTOINCREMENT on the primary key.

Comment: What are `shows`, `dates`, and `batch` variables? Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not an answer, but the error seems to imply that something is trying to insert `index` values which are already present in the table.  This shouldn't ever be happening, because ideally you would not need to manually assign values to the `index` column.

Comment: It seems on the second load the auto increment is resetting.  Will dig into SQLLite a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by removing the primary key. Not ideal.

Seems the problem is Pandas to_sql() - it is looking for an index field that it's using but it resets on each execution.

The problem was caused with the latest version of Pandas defaulting to creating an Index column.  This was conflicting with my primary key.  I just had to add : index=False as a parameter to .to_sql